# Can't Change ImageView Background in GridLayout Android

Tags: android

I'm using gridlayout with xml layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:columnCount="8"
        app:rowCount="8"
        >
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/papan8a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@drawable/white_queen"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bidak8a"
        android:background="@drawable/black_rook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contoh"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/papan8b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/kuningDikit"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="0.5"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bidak8b"
        android:background="@drawable/black_rook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contoh"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="1"
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output is like this :

[image]

ImageView should become a yellow background for my textView, but it's never showed. Eventhough I put `android:background="#FF0000"` imageView never changes. So what's the problem here...? am I missing something in my gridlayout...??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I wanna make imageView as a plane and textview on it...It's like a chess game Mr. @Prasad...

Comment: For your requirement you can use only imageview with background and src attribute, and also check your imageview images size, it may be possible it is smaller than textview image size and therefore it hides behind texiview

Comment: http://coding4ataraxia.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-display-chessboard-on-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `android:background` to `android:src=""` and it became visible now.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/papan8a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"                
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/latar_kuning"
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning a background to the textviews, instead set the src attribute to the transparent image and background to the desired background color on one of the image views?

Comment: Iyaps... I'm sure it's a transparent image mr. Zachary... :)

Comment: Instead of assigning a background to the textviews, instead set the src attribute to the transparent image and background to the desired background color on one of the image views?

Comment: ooowh.. So I have to use src ... okiee.. Lemme try Mr. Zach... ;)

Comment: Yes, with images that have transparent backgrounds you can set the background attribute to the desired background color and then the src attribute to the image. By doing so you can eliminate the need to assign a background value to the textview. If doing so doesnt solve your problem, perhaps try taking the imageview you just altered and the text view and place them in a relativelayout inside the gridLayout with that relative layout being assigned the specific row and column number.

Comment: You're welcome! I modified my answer to the solution of your issue above, marked as solved if it's fully functional and acceptable!

Comment: Eeeeh.....Btw.. but for the next imageView in another coulumb, it doesn't work... :'(
It just work for row 0, colom 0,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background, use src to set Imageview background.

hope this will work

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/papan8a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"                
            app:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/xxxx"
            />
```

Comment: If I use android:src, It only works for the first coulumb, but the second or the next coulumb, it's still unvisible

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set background direct to Textview. What is the purpose of using ImageView for setting background to the TextView.

set background to the Textview and check if it solves your problem